# Listfragment not showing list

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-activity

I tried to modify this code http://code.google.com/p/krvarma-android-samples/source/browse/trunk/RSSReader/src/com/varma/samples/rssreader/ui/RSSListActivity.java

in order to make it work with my program, it looks like my parsing is working ok , but the list is not displaying, and im sure that the rest of my resources are the same as the link above , did i hopefully mess up something obvious?

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class newsFragment extends SherlockListFragment{

    private ArrayList<RSSItem> itemlist = null;
    private RSSListAdaptor rssadaptor = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.news_layout);

        itemlist = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();

        new RetrieveRSSFeeds().execute();
    }

    @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    RSSItem data = itemlist.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(data.link));

    startActivity(intent);
}

private void retrieveRSSFeed(String urlToRssFeed,ArrayList<RSSItem> list)
{
    try
    {
       URL url = new URL(urlToRssFeed);
       SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
       SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
       XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
       RSSParser theRssHandler = new RSSParser(list);

       xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRssHandler);

       InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());

       xmlreader.parse(is);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class RetrieveRSSFeeds extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog progress = null;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        retrieveRSSFeed("http://www.krvarma.com/feed",itemlist);

        rssadaptor = new RSSListAdaptor(getActivity(), R.layout.rssitemview,itemlist);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(
                getActivity(), null, "Loading RSS Feeds...");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setListAdapter(rssadaptor);

        progress.dismiss();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}

private class RSSListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>{
    private List<RSSItem> objects = null;

    public RSSListAdaptor(Context context, int textviewid, List<RSSItem> objects) {
        super(context, textviewid, objects);

        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != objects) ? objects.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RSSItem getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != objects) ? objects.get(position) : null);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(null == view)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitemview, null);
        }

        RSSItem data = objects.get(position);

        if(null != data)
        {
            TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            TextView date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            TextView description = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);

            title.setText(data.title);
            date.setText("on " + data.date);
            description.setText(data.description);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: retrieveRSSFeed("http://www.krvarma.com/feed") is this your feed? Because the link is invalid..

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem with your code is this line:

```
getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.news_layout);
```

Is there a reason to why you decided to set the content view for the activity from a fragment's `onCreate()` method, a fragment that is probably declared in that layout file? Remove the line above and let the activity manage its own layout file.